# Is it possible to add help text to addressfield module fields?

Tags: entities

I would like to add some help info to address field fields from Address Field Module (http://drupal.org/project/addressfield). Is that possible, or do I have to use Javascript?

Comment: you can use [hook_field_display_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_display_alter/7) to alter the field.

Comment: Sorry, guess I should have asked. Do you want this to be static information displayed on the edit form (help the end user know what to enter), or do you want to add additional fields to the address field for the end user to fill in?

Comment: just static info to help the users

Answer (score 0):

When editing the field settings there should be a **Help text** field where you can enter "Instructions to present to the user below this field on the editing form".

If you want to provide additional instructions, use the [Markup](http://drupal.org/project/markup) module to add a "field" containing the additional instructions. To keep the address field and the markup field in the same fieldset, use the [Field group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module to group the two fields into a single fieldset group.

Comment: Yes, but the address field from the Address Field module are not shown - form what i understand, you have to use them as they are, so I can't access those fields (or am I wrong?)
I'll check the Markup module. Thank you for your suggestions!